# Storing a list of objects and adding to that list using useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange, use-state

I have to store a list of objects in an array using useState hook in React. 
I have input fields with onChange on them which i get the value of and try put/update it in one of the objects in the list.
The inputs are in a tables like structure and each row represents a set. Each column is reps, rpe and weight. These values belong to each set and need to be saved in an object in the array. Currently when you edit, it doesn't save everything you've done but rather just saves the last thing you did in that row.

```js
const [sets, setSets] = useState([]);
    const [numSets, setNumSets] = useState(1);
    const [tableSets, setTablesSets] = useState([]);

    const repsOnChangeHandler = index => e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //let x = tableSets.push(value);
        console.log(index)
        let tempArray=[...tableSets];
        tempArray[index] = {...tempArray[index], reps: e.target.value}
        setTablesSets(tempArray);
    }

    const rpeOnChangeHandler = index => e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //let x = tableSets.push(value);
        let tempArray=[...tableSets];
        tempArray[index] = {...tempArray[index], rpe: e.target.value}
        setTablesSets(tempArray);
    }

    const weightOnChangeHandler = index => e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //let x = tableSets.push(value);
        let tempArray=[...tableSets];
        tempArray[index] = {...tableSets[index], weight: e.target.value}
        setTablesSets(tempArray);
    }

    const addSetHandler = () => {

        let temp = {
            reps: 0,
            rpe: 0,
            weight: 0
        };
        setTablesSets(tableSets.concat(temp));

        let x = numSets;
        setNumSets(x + 1);
        
        setSets([...sets, {
            id: sets.length,
            setValue: <li key={sets.length} className={classes.TableRow}>
                <input type="number" min="1" readOnly="readonly" className={classes.TableInput} value={numSets} />
                <input type="number" min="1" max="40" className={classes.TableInput} onChange={repsOnChangeHandler(numSets-1)} />
                <input type="number" min="1" max="10" className={classes.TableInput} onChange={rpeOnChangeHandler(numSets-1)} />
                <input type="number" min="1" className={classes.TableInput} onChange={weightOnChangeHandler(numSets-1)} />
            </li>
        }]);
    }
```

Comment: No that doesn't work. You have to do it the way i did it to get the event

Comment: prepare [mcve] on codesandbox?

Comment: no actual `value` in inputs?

Comment: The value that i get is correct it just seems to wipe the state when i try to edit the state. I guess the main problem I'm having is trying to just edit e.g. reps in the first object in the list

Comment: `console.log(index)` shows...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const repsOnChangeHandler = index => e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(index)
        let tempArray = [...tableSets];
        tempArray[index].reps = e.target.value
        setTablesSets(tempArray);
    }

    const rpeOnChangeHandler = index => e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let tempArray = [...tableSets];
        tempArray[index].rpe = e.target.value
        setTablesSets(tempArray);
    }

    const weightOnChangeHandler = index => e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let tempArray = [...tableSets];
        tempArray[index].weight = e.target.value;
        setTablesSets(tempArray);
    }
```

These are the changes that were needed to fix it